# How can I use the Del, Esc or Tab keys with the THotkey component?

Tags: delphi

Delphi7 `THotkey` component (from Win32 tab) doesn't allow entering these keys: Del, Esc, Tab.
Ie, during runtime you focus THotkey control, you type these keys into control, but control doesn't show (remember) them.

Maybe somehow it's possible to enter these keys (Del, Esc, Tab) into THotkey control?

Comment: What are you trying to do. And what exactly is the question? You seem to say, X cannot be done. How do I do X?

Comment: Also, did you read my answer to your previous Q? This shows how you can take matters into your own hands.

Comment: @David, I corrected the Q. It was formulated bad

Comment: What was wrong on understanding the problem asked here ? It's just *"How to enter DEL, ESC and TAB keys into the THotkey component ?"* In my view was and still is well understandable and valid question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not possible to enter these keys to the `THotKey` control. The windows 'hot key control', that the control is based on, ignores these keys, and some others too as specified in the below quote.

This is from 'Default Hot Key Message Processing' in [About Hot Key Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775233%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> **WM_SYSKEYDOWN**
>   Calls the DefWindowProc function if the key is ENTER,
>   TAB, SPACE BAR, DEL, ESC, or BACKSPACE. If the key is SHIFT, CTRL, or
>   ALT, it checks whether the combination is valid and, if it is, sets
>   the hot key using the combination. All other keys are set as hot keys
>   without their validity being checked first.